# Intercept Ctrl-V or WM_PASTE in AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser and do cleanup

Tags: .net, axwebbrowser

I am using a winform **HTML Editor** which uses `AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser`.
User are copying and pasting text from other software into this control.
The problem is that, on paste <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> it add few font tags to preserve formatting.
I do not want to preserve formatting, it should paste clean text without formatting or at least should not add there `FONT` tags.
What i think is to intercept <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> and before pasting cleanup clipboard text.

So, I tried to intercept `WM_PASTE` message and replace clipboard content with fixed test (just to check) as below

```
class myWB : AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x302)     // Trap WM_PASTE:
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetText("some text");
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

But it was not working. I added following before IF block to see if it is receiving `WM_PASTE` message.

```
Debug.WriteLine(m.Msg);
```

On run, i didn't see there 0x302 (770) in output window even after multiple <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

Is it not receiving that message?

Then what is the way to do it? How do i cleanup text before paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WM_PASTE is not a notification, it is a *command*. That you'd send to an EDIT control to have it paste the clipboard into the control.

Of course a web browser is not an edit box so doesn't do it the same way.  You will need to intercept the IHtmlElement2.onpaste event instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Can you please provide some reference/link where i could find some help on how to handle `IHtmlElement2.onpaste` event for `AxWebbrowser`.

Comment: Just type "onpaste event" in a google query.  All the top links look relevant.

Comment: Ok i created `IHtmlElement2` as `IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)editorWebBrowser.Document;` but there is no onpaste event? for doc object ?

Comment: You create an IHTMLDocument2.  Get an IHtmlElement2 from the Body property.

Comment: I took `HtmlEventProxy` class from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25769/Handling-HTML-Events-from-NET-using-C) and attached `onpaste` event for body `IHtmlElement2` but still it is not working. Due to lack of time i applied a dirty trick. I used Activate event of form and cleaning up clipboard text. i know is not a good thing but right now i do not have time to dig into issue. May be see later.